# Android Studio "NavigationDrawer": How to implement a basic GoogleMap?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, navigation-drawer, drawer

I have to learn, but for YOU it is simple:

I created a simple basic  NavigationDrawer-app with Android Studio (the offered NavigationDrawer you can choose when creating a new app).

My question: How (or where) can I put my GoogleMap-fragment? Can I replace the "PlaceholderFragment" or do I create a new Fragment? And how to implement?

May I ask for a LITTLE and EASY example or hint? As I said, just an absolute simple running NavigationDrawer/GoogleMap app. I know a lot about GoogleMap, but I don't get the fusion.

Thanks for any little help and best regards from Germany.

Answer (score 0):

you can replace the `PlaceHolderFragment` generated with your own `Fragment`, be it a regular fragment or a GoogleMap fragment.

The private `PlaceHolderFragment` class is created for your convenience, but you could just create a separate `Fragment` class and remove the `PlaceHolderFragment` class. You would open your map fragment instead of the PlaceHolderFragment inside the method `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected` in the Activity created with the project template.

```
@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, MyMapFragment.newInstance(position + 1)) // instead of PHF
            .commit();
}
```

Hope this helps.